# A counting poem or song

Tags: numbers, numerals, music

There are some traditional songs that are very repetitive and involve counting up or down.
The only English example I know is "99 bottles of beer", and I know two in Finnish: "the elephant march" (elefanttimarssi) and "three crows" (kolme varista), where on counts elephants up from one or crows down from three.
There must be numerous examples out there.

Are there similar songs or poems in Latin where you count up or down?
Classical metric poetry is not flexible for things like this, but songs or poems from later eras could do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonable to postulate the existence of such songs at Rome, but is it likely that authentic examples would survive from classical times? The structure of Republican society would not have helped with their dissemination beyond their places of origin, and I doubt that there would be much incentive to preserve such ephemera in permanent form — though we might expect to find some graffito or other at Pompeii, say, one of these days, in the course of practical archaeology.

[There are indeed English counting songs, but they won't help at all. They include Twelve Green Bottles, One Man Went to Mow, and Twelve Days of Christmas (the last a useful demonstration of the binomial theorem for the mathematically inclined).]